# Sorting elements with Array.Sort() not sorting the first element

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I've been using Array.Sort() to sort an array of string, but for some reason it is keeping the first element of the array and outputting not in order.

```
    private void quicksort1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        String[] parts = new String[1000];

        //System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
        System.IO.StreamWriter output = new System.IO.StreamWriter("OUTPUT.txt");

        parts = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
        foreach (string s in parts)
        {
                Array.Sort(parts);
                parts.Equals(s);
                output.WriteLine(s);
                counter++;

        }
        output.WriteLine("There were" + " "  + counter + " " + "lines read in.");

        output.Close();
```

I was just wondering if there was a possible solution to where Array.Sort() would sort the first element as well as the others.

Comment: Why do you sort the array every iteration?

Comment: Why do you think it is NOT sorting the first element?

Comment: I think @Vipar is on to something. Sorting the `parts` object when it is being referenced by the `foreach` loop may have some unintended side-effects. Have you tried moving the `Array.Sort(parts);` statement to before the start of the loop?

Comment: The problem is that @Stock is pulling the value out *before* the sort occurs, so the first print is the value from the unsorted array, but after that, it's always going to be taking the value from the array after sort (but it's doing a lot of other things it shouldn't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you're sorting the entire set once per line.  Instead, you can just sort the lines once in advance of your loop.

In your current code, the first line *appears* unsorted because you're fetching it prior to the sort:

```
foreach (string s in parts) // Getting s from the original array
{
   Array.Sort(parts);  //Sorting array
   // s is unchanged - at this point its still the first element from the original array
```

Instead, sort up front.  Try this:

```
private void quicksort1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var output = new System.IO.StreamWriter("OUTPUT.txt"))
  {
    string[] parts = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
    Array.Sort(parts);
    foreach (string s in parts)
    {
        output.WriteLine(s);
    }

    output.WriteLine("There were {0} lines read in.", parts.Length);
  }
```

}

Note that there is also no need for a `counter` variable here, and switching the code to use the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) simplifies the logic a bit.

Comment: Now I'm trying to do this with integers, but the output would be something like "1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4" how would I get it to sort the values? Sorry, I'm relatively new to C# and programming.

Comment: @Stock Convert it to integers up front.  LINQ can be good for this, ie:  `var partNumbers = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text).Select(line => Convert.ToInt32(line)).OrderBy(i => i);`  That will return the numbers already sorted

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to how to output this to a file, sorry to bother.

Comment: @Stock: `File.WriteAllLines("OUTPUT.txt", partNumbers.Select(i => i.ToString()));`

Comment: Now I'm getting a FormatException, input string was not in a correct format. My input file is just a simple text file

Comment: @Stock The above will give that if there is a line that isn't a number (and can't be parsed into an int). THat includes blank lines (you'd have to handle them separately)

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be outside of the loop (before the loop that is): `Array.Sort(parts);`

By the time you have done the sort, you're already accessing the first element.  The first element is getting sorted in the Array, you've just accessed it in it's previous position in the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the first line using the line `output.WriteLine(s)`.  The problem is that `s` is retrieved from your list before the list is sorted.